# Light and old-browsers compatible alternative for JSON in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

Im getting a text response from my server stored in a javascript var. I have complete control of the format of this response. Normally this text response have 3 elements I need, ideally i will like to use `json.parse` to solve my problems like:

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1, "state":"ON"}',
obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert(obj.result);
alert(obj.count);
alert(obj.state);
```

Elegant and simple, but [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=JSON.parse) like IE8,7,6 do not support json.parse. At this point I have two possible solutions, one of course is to use Jquery, but i dont want because i want to keep my code small as possible, and two could be using a library like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) that handles for me the incompatibility issues like jquery does, but then again, same problem, too much code for such a simple function.

So I think the best approach will be to change the response format to something like `true%1%ON` and then split around `%`, what do you think? seems to me a bit dirty.

Answer (score 3):

You can pluck out the code for the parser from an existing library instead of having everything, since you only need the parser. An example would be plucking out [the implementation of `$.parseJSON` (lines 523-551)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/core.js#L523) from the jQuery core. Apparently it uses the `new Function` approach instead of `eval`.

Comment: eval is a part of Javascript, it's not a part of the JSON libraries of Crockford

Comment: @Kenneth apparently you haven't read the README of json2. It uses `eval` with additional safeguards. If the OP doesn't want the additional code, he can use `eval` directly.

Comment: OK, I understand now. Could you rephrase it maybe? Now it looks like your saying eval is a part of JSON libraries of Crockford

Answer (score 1):

Before I get berated on not reading the question, let me rephrase:

Using the `json2.js` library, in my opinion (not that it matters), would not lead to a significant performance loss it is also not a lot of code to include especially when minimized:

```
if(typeof JSON!=="object"){JSON={}}(function(){"use strict";function f(e){return e<10?"0"+e:e}function quote(e){escapable.lastIndex=0;return escapable.test(e)?'"'+e.replace(escapable,function(e){var t=meta[e];return typeof t==="string"?t:"\\u"+("0000"+e.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4)})+'"':'"'+e+'"'}function str(e,t){var n,r,i,s,o=gap,u,a=t[e];if(a&&typeof a==="object"&&typeof a.toJSON==="function"){a=a.toJSON(e)}if(typeof rep==="function"){a=rep.call(t,e,a)}switch(typeof a){case"string":return quote(a);case"number":return isFinite(a)?String(a):"null";case"boolean":case"null":return String(a);case"object":if(!a){return"null"}gap+=indent;u=[];if(Object.prototype.toString.apply(a)==="[object Array]"){s=a.length;for(n=0;n<s;n+=1){u[n]=str(n,a)||"null"}i=u.length===0?"[]":gap?"[\n"+gap+u.join(",\n"+gap)+"\n"+o+"]":"["+u.join(",")+"]";gap=o;return i}if(rep&&typeof rep==="object"){s=rep.length;for(n=0;n<s;n+=1){if(typeof rep[n]==="string"){r=rep[n];i=str(r,a);if(i){u.push(quote(r)+(gap?": ":":")+i)}}}}else{for(r in a){if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a,r)){i=str(r,a);if(i){u.push(quote(r)+(gap?": ":":")+i)}}}}i=u.length===0?"{}":gap?"{\n"+gap+u.join(",\n"+gap)+"\n"+o+"}":"{"+u.join(",")+"}";gap=o;return i}}if(typeof Date.prototype.toJSON!=="function"){Date.prototype.toJSON=function(e){return isFinite(this.valueOf())?this.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+f(this.getUTCMonth()+1)+"-"+f(this.getUTCDate())+"T"+f(this.getUTCHours())+":"+f(this.getUTCMinutes())+":"+f(this.getUTCSeconds())+"Z":null};String.prototype.toJSON=Number.prototype.toJSON=Boolean.prototype.toJSON=function(e){return this.valueOf()}}var cx=/[\u0000\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,escapable=/[\\\"\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,gap,indent,meta={"\b":"\\b","   ":"\\t","\n":"\\n","\f":"\\f","\r":"\\r",'"':'\\"',"\\":"\\\\"},rep;if(typeof JSON.stringify!=="function"){JSON.stringify=function(e,t,n){var r;gap="";indent="";if(typeof n==="number"){for(r=0;r<n;r+=1){indent+=" "}}else if(typeof n==="string"){indent=n}rep=t;if(t&&typeof t!=="function"&&(typeof t!=="object"||typeof t.length!=="number")){throw new Error("JSON.stringify")}return str("",{"":e})}}if(typeof JSON.parse!=="function"){JSON.parse=function(text,reviver){function walk(e,t){var n,r,i=e[t];if(i&&typeof i==="object"){for(n in i){if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(i,n)){r=walk(i,n);if(r!==undefined){i[n]=r}else{delete i[n]}}}}return reviver.call(e,t,i)}var j;text=String(text);cx.lastIndex=0;if(cx.test(text)){text=text.replace(cx,function(e){return"\\u"+("0000"+e.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4)})}if(/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(text.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g,"@").replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g,"]").replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g,""))){j=eval("("+text+")");return typeof reviver==="function"?walk({"":j},""):j}throw new SyntaxError("JSON.parse")}}})()
```

You can drop it in using only one line and be done with it. Writing your own syntax for something that's already been done is going to take a lot of time away from doing the other work to finish your project. Any code that you will write will have to go through the same rigorous testing as this `json` library which has been time tested and proven to work.

This one line of code is a `3KB` file.

[json on github](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Answer (score 0):

Well, like you said, you have two options:

- either include a library like JSON2 (which is 17KB uncompressed, so not a big burden)
- Build your own little parser

And then there's a third option which is potential security issue, but it might do:
use eval to evaluate the json:

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1, "state":"ON"}';
obj = eval(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [json-sans-eval](https://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/). It is fast and small (only 1.5Kb), but does not validate your JSON.